# Android GCM: different way of handling push depending on whether the app is visible or not

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've got a couple of activities and an intent service which handles GCM incoming messages.

Right now for every push, I'm sending a Notification, and after the user clicks it, he is redirected to appropriate screen.

I would like to alter this behavior that if the app is visible (any activity is in the foreground), instead of the notification a dialog message is shown (with appropriate action).

Any idea how to implement it?

I have 2 ideas but none of them is perfect:

- Keep track of every activity in the application, if the activity is visible, don't show notification, but sent an intent to the activity (not nice solution)
- register/unregister the second broadcast receiver in each activity's onResume/onPause, "catch" the incoming GCM broadcast (I'm not sure if it is possible).

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it, but the docs say you can get the [number of running activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html#numRunning) per each task.

Try to find your application's task among currently running tasks:

```
ActivityManager acitivityManager = (ActivityManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
// Get the top of running tasks, limit by 100
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = acitivityManager.getRunningTasks(100);
for (RunningTaskInfo taskInfo : tasks) {
    if (YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.equals(taskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName())) {
        if (taskInfo.numRunning > 0) {
            // Show dialog
        } else {
            // Show notification
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Google added a note on `getRunningTasks()`:

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces. This should never be used for core logic in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based on the information found here. Such uses are not supported, and will likely break in the future. For example, if multiple applications can be actively running at the same time, assumptions made about the meaning of the data here for purposes of control flow will be incorrect.

So use it at your own risk.

---

Also check if GCM broadcasts are [ordered](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#isOrderedBroadcast%28%29). If so, you can "override" your default `BroadcastReceiver` with the other ones in each Activity. Just play with the [priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29) of `IntentFilter`s. When the `BroadcastReceiver` with higher priority receives the message, it can [abort](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) it's further propagation. For your application this means that when some `Activity` is running, it registers the receiver which shows the dialog and aborts broadcast. If no activity is active, then your default receiver shows the notification.

Comment: I didn't want to use the first solution because of the reason you mentioned. 
The second solution seems to be promissiong, I will check it

Comment: GCM broadcasts are indeed ordered! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution (idea 1):

To detect whether your app is running back- or foreground, you can simply set a boolean in onPause/onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  runningOnBackground = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  runningOnBackground = true;
}
```

When you start a new intent from an notification this method gets called: (if you are using singleTop), with the boolean you can determine what to do in the onNewIntent method.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent){
  if(runningOnBackground){
    //do this
  }
  else{
    //do that
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: well, actually I was trying to avoid this. If you have a couple of Activities, the code gets complicated and there is also a transition when switching the activities. If the push comes in during this state, it may not be handled properly.